# Calculating Recursion Space Complexity

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, big-o

While I have watched numerous tutorials and read textbook readings, I cannot get a clear answer on calculating recursion space complexity.

Most explanations leverage very simple recursion functions, such as the factorial one below:

```
def factorial(n):
  if n == 1:
    return 1
  return n * factorial(n - 1)
```

In examples like the one above, the actual function itself takes O(1) auxiliary space. However, since this is a recursion function, we must also consider the fact that calls will simultaneously occupy stack frames on the call stack. The maximum number of stack frames required to execute this function is achieved when we are at our maximum recursion depth. In this case, if we consider n to be our initial function call at level 0, our maximum depth will be achieved at level n - 1, meaning there are n total levels. Therefore, the number of stack frames required is directly proportional to n; the space complexity is O(n).

While these examples are educational and helpful, I cannot find examples where the actual function does not have a space complexity of O(1). Suppose, for example, that we have the dummy recursion function below:

```
def factorial(n):
  cool = [i for i in range(n)]
  if n == 1:
    return 1
  return n * factorial(n - 1)
```

The only difference is that our function now creates a list with a length equal to n on each function call; therefore, the (non-recursive) function has a space complexity of O(n). So, in a situation such as this, how do we ultimately compute the total space complexity for the recursive function, factoring in the call stack as well?

Do we sum the space occupied by a single recursive function on each level (level 0 to level n - 1) and apply Big O notation to it?

In this case, a single function call on our 0th level would require n space, a single function call on our 1st level would require n - 1 space, a single function call on our 2nd level would require n - 2 space, etc.

So, the total space can be expressed by the following n-termed sum:

n + n - 1 + n - 2 + .... + 2 + 1 = n(n + 1) / 2

So, using big O notation, the space complexity would simplify to O(n^2). Is this correct? More broadly, I would like to know how to calculate recursion space complexity, particularly when our function itself does not have O(1) auxiliary space.

Comment: I am not a computer scientist, but this logic makes sense to me. Note, however, that the answer for you second problem depends on the implementation and the compiler. Some really smart compiles may figure out that the "cool" variable is not used, so they may not actually compute and store it.

Comment: Your second function is still O(1) for stack space. The list is created in the heap (all Python objects are). The stack only holds reference to it (your `cool` variable). There is no way to dynamically allocate space on the stack of a function in Python, so the stack frame of any function always has a known constant size. With this said, of course the total space used is still in the order of O(n^2).

Comment: @lategamelank Everything you wrote is correct. Only your last question does not make sense ;) You are asking someone to explain to you something that you have quite nicely explained yourself. It seems clear to me that you need no explanation from anyone :D

Comment: This is extremely tricky to analyze, because, unlike runtime, different programming languages will result in different (asymptotic) space usage for the same recursive algorithm. For example, some programming languages will be able to compile a recursive algorithm into an iterative one (using much less space) using tail recursion. This would be inherently tied to the programming language in question (some will have restrictions on how stacks work that would prevent this.)